# Why are pose estimators so slow?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, face-detection, pose-estimation

I'm new to the ML field and have a question about computer vision. Why can face detection and object detection software (such as Instagram's face filters) be run on our smart phones at 30 - 60 FPS smoothly, while pose estimation software (e.g OpenPose) struggle to process real time video at above 10 FPS (with decent specs too)?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but Snapchat's software can track your face until poor lighting and pretty abrupt movement and he same can be done with pose estimation, but requiring better/more GPUS and running at a lower FPS.

What would be the fastest type of neural network to use for real time pose estimation and what components make up a robust neural network that can accurately predict a person's pose in real time?

Is it even possible to perform some much computation and still achieve relatively high FPS?

Any response is appreciated

Comment: I think you should try this example by Intel's OpenVINO guys - [Link](https://github.com/opencv/openvino_training_extensions/tree/develop/pytorch_toolkit/human_pose_estimation). On an RTX 2060, I could achieve upto 20+ FPS on using Python + PyTorch

Answer (score 0):

Pure detection is always slow. The most common walk around is to use detection -> tracking -> update framework.

In display thread,  video is shown at constant 30 fps. <- this is what user will see and will not feel the pain in the ass lag.

Backend, you pose detection is constantly update to the pose model( predicted by e.g. EKF or another way). EKF is able to output model at 30 hz corresponding to the display thread frequency.   In between, if you have face update, you can also update the correlation face model to local predict the small step/baseline pose motion with larger varance. At key pose update step, give low variance to this update to perform the major update.